# SSO Laravel Passport

Tags: laravel, passport

Всем привет! Столкнулась с такой задачей: необходимо разрешить пользователям нескольких приложений (например, 3 приложения) laravel с разными доменами авторизоваться через четвертое приложение. База данных одинакова для всех. и желательно авторизовать так, чтобы пользователь вообще этого не заметил, т.е. без нажатия кнопки входа в систему. Приходит на сайт - а он уже залогинен. Я пыталась использовать passport Laravel. В сети нашла некоторые расплывчатые решения но они меня не устраивают. 
Я полностью установила и настроила паспорт на сервере для аутентификации. есть страница, где можно добавить клиентов и токены OAuth для личного доступа, созданы несколько клиентов для разных сайтов для Auth::user, но я не знаю, что делать дальше.
Подскажите пожалуйста что делать с этим. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Как то не очень понятно, что вам не понятно, вы не можете понять как заголовки с авторизацией послать или что ?

Comment: мне просто не ясно что делать дальше в принципе. примеров в сети не нашла.как  все-таки авторизовать пользователя на сайте А через сайт D, в примеру, какая последовательность действий. Может я что-то теоритически еще чего-то не знаю/не понимаю

Comment: Блин ну расписывать времени сильно нету, но идея такая вы первый раз посылаете запрос с логином паролем, говорите что все ок , и выдаете ключ, который создали в Laravel passoport, ключ у клиента сохраняете и шлете потом в заголовках, OAuth, почитаейте какие там ныжы, еще вот есть [вопрос](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/code-review/api-authentication-with-passport) и вот [видео](https://laracasts.com/series/whats-new-in-laravel-5-3/episodes/13)